Click event does not fire if redirect occurred
I have a few simple links like <a href="deeplink://link-to-app" class="link" data-app="App name" /> and event listener inside window.onload
Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('link')).forEach(element => {
    element.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
            document.cookie = `appName=${event.target.closest('.link').getAttribute('data-app')}; expires=${cookieExpires}; domain=${domain}`
         })
    })

When opened in a mobile browser, click events are only triggered if there is no transition to the application. In a situation where a mobile application is opened, click events do not work

You could try and make it <a href="#" ...>, and then do location.href = "deeplink://link-to-app"; in your click handler, after setting the cookie, and see if that changes anything.

Your solution didn't work(

What do you mean by "click events do not work"? You mean it's just following the link without running the JS?

BTW, you don't need to use Array.from(). NodeList has a forEach() method.

It's hard to explain the behavior. I can say that if a link is followed, the cookie entry is not updated.

I already tried solution with promise chaining like Promise.resolve().then(() => { document.cookie =  }).then(() => { location.href =  }), but still not working
